# How to plot using pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to plot two independent columns: the first one represents data, the second one represents time:

```
All_packets= df.select("ip_adr_src","asn_val","timestamp")
EB_packets=All_packets.filter("asn_val is not NULL")
EB_packets.show()
plotdf=EB_packets.select("asn_val","timestamp")
```

I want to plot `ans_val` group by `ip_adr_src per time`. 
If I have 6 `ip_adr_src`, I expect to have 6 curves.

```
+--------------------+---------------------------------+-------------+
|     ip_adr_src     |asn_val                          |    timestamp|
+--------------------+---------------------------------+-------------+
|14:15:92:cc:00:01...|                              707|1539071748441|
|14:15:92:cc:00:02...|                             1212|1539071752314|
|14:15:92:cc:00:00...|                             1616|1539071755578|
|14:15:92:cc:00:04...|                             1818|1539071757167|
|14:15:92:cc:00:03...|                             2020|1539071759297|
|14:15:92:cc:00:00...|                             2121|1539071760408|
|14:15:92:cc:00:09...|                             2323|1539071764035|
|14:15:92:cc:00:07...|                             2424|1539071765775|
|14:15:92:cc:00:00...|                             2525|1539071768560|
|14:15:92:cc:00:06...|                             5858|1539071845370|
|14:15:92:cc:00:00...|                             6060|1539071850129|
|14:15:92:cc:00:05...|                             6262|1539071855046|
|14:15:92:cc:00:00...|                             6969|1539071872523|
|14:15:92:cc:00:07...|                             6969|1539071872528|
|14:15:92:cc:00:08...|                             7171|1539071877609|
```

But, all my tests are wrong and I have this error:

```
Dataframe doesn't have an object `'plot'`
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood which column you want to plot, but I suspect you need help on how to plot. This is how I would plot an `ans_val` column against a `timestamp` one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_ans_val = [val.ans_val for val in df.select('ans_val').collect()]
x_ts = [val.timestamp for val in df.select('timestamp').collect()]

plt.plot(x_ts, y_ans_val)

plt.ylabel('ans_val')
plt.xlabel('timestamp')
plt.title('ASN values for time')
plt.legend(['asn_val'], loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

If you need to plot other columns, call the `plt.plot(x,y)` command multiple time, and add each name in `plt.legend(your_cols, loc='upper left')` function.